# Swift 4 Just added WatchKit and got cannot be registered to your development team

Tags: ios, swift

I just added WatchKit App to my iOS Swift 4 Application and then I try to run it and I get this error:

> The app ID "MyApp.watchkitapp.watchkitextension" cannot be registered
>   to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique
>   string to try again.

So I changed my Watch Extension Bundle Id then I get this error:

> :-1: Embedded binary's bundle identifier is not prefixed with the
>   parent app's bundle identifier.
>
> Embedded Binary Bundle
>   Identifier:   Company.Watch.watchkitapp.watchkitextension          Parent App
>   Bundle Identifier: Company.MyApp.watchkitapp

Then I change the bundle Id for watchkitapp and then I get this error:

> :-1: Embedded binary's bundle identifier is not prefixed with the
>   parent app's bundle identifier.
>
> Embedded Binary Bundle Identifier:    Company.Watch.watchkitapp Parent
>   App Bundle Identifier:        Company.MyApp

I think this is telling me to watch everything back to MyApp, but then I would run into the other errors again. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that your development team already has an app with that bundle identifier. Try changing your initial bundle identifier to a different one. 
Make sure all your targets bundle identifiers line up like this:

- YourApp: `com.yourcompany.UniqueNameForThisApp`
- YourApp WatchKit App: `com.yourcompany.UniqueNameForThisApp.watchkitapp`
- YourApp WatchKit Extension: `com.yourcompany.UniqueNameForThisApp.watchkitapp.watchkitextension`